# how to display names of employee ending with 'tt' from an employee table in mssql

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2005

how to display names of employee ending with 'tt' from an employee table  in mssql

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from Employee
where Lastname like '%tt'
```

Comment: How can i do this in MS access 2007

Comment: @user495854: Change the `%` to a `*`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE RIGHT(Lastname, 2) = 'tt'
```

Comment: here you can use functional index on the lastname column, while indexing won't work by the like '%tt' version

Comment: You got that right Zoltan, hence query will be faster... hell, you can even force case sensitive search with collation